# How can I release the latch bolt on this damaged door knob?

Tags: doors

It seems entirely screwed - there isn't even a locking mechanism left it seems. What can I even do here without causing even more damage to the door frame?

[image]

Comment: Wow, everyone is _far_ more pedantic than I usually am on this one! The door is "locked" because the bolt is still in the strike plate of the frame, therefore, it doesn't just push open. All parts of the handle _except_ the bolt have been removed, whether in a violent manner that caused the utter destruction of the handle or because the knob didn't work and the good Sergeant carefully disassembled the rest is indeterminable and irrelevant to the question of how to get this part out.

Comment: @FreeMan, the problem is that we don't see the bolt extension--we see the _housing_ for it, which doesn't move. What would have to be done is hidden inside the small bore. I think.

Comment: Might be easier to take the pins out of the hinges (if they're accessible) and open the door that way

Comment: I read it as "how do I make this attack work next time" unless we are dealing with a serious translation problem. Admittedly the photo would be pretty brazen, but... well, we are all lucky that folks with intelligence tend to have better answers than burglary or assault. Apologies if I'm misreading, but it isn't only online security where paranoia isn't always enough

Comment: @AlanBirtles I suggest making your comment on pulling the hinge pins on the door an answer, that looks to me like it is precisely what may solve the problem.  While making that an answer put in some whys, hows, and caveats to flesh it out a bit.

Comment: @MacGuffin that's why its just a comment, removing the hinge pins from a door isn't something I've ever done, no detailed idea how to do it or how not to do it just that it is theoretically a way of bypassing a door lock

Comment: Should be able to use a flexible piece of material between the door and frame to push the latch back to open the door, since this is a knob and not a deadbolt. It may have a locking pin but it's rare that those are installed correctly enough to work. Sometimes this is called "credit carding" but I wouldn't try with a credit card, maybe an old library card or something.

Comment: What are the 2 semicircles visible on the door frame?  Were they there before the damage?  If so, did they serve a purpose before the damage?

Comment: @keshlam Sounds like you are used to some really well mannered burglars, wanting to avoid damaging the wood (after already having entirely obliterated the knob, so avoiding detection can't be a concern).

Comment: Actually, I'm used to burglars who wouldn't be so incompetent as to bash off the knob, not know what to do, and then take a photo to be used against them as evidence. But I don't see how else this question could have been asked this way. Unless, _perhaps,_ it's a translation problem.

Comment: "What are the 2 semicircles visible on the door frame? Were they there before the damage? If so, did they serve a purpose before the damage?"  My guess is this is damage done by someone moving something big through the door at some time.  There's no apparent matching damage to the door so the door was likely open when that damage was done.  Also, it appears this is painted wood, it might just be a defect in the wood that was considered insignificant at the time.

Answer (score 10):

That doesn't look like "fell apart". That looks like "was destroyed with a vengeance". You can try to grab onto what's left and pull sideways, but I can't even suggest what to pull as critical parts seem missing.

It used to look something like this:

[image]

#1 is what you have left (in part). It doesn't move, and therefore doesn't help you release the bolt (#3). #2 is the moveable bolt extension, which you'd normally just slide over to open the door.

You're going to have to find an **angled pliers** or similar and see if you can get it on the back of the actual bolt. There may be a small tab that used to engage a slide mechanism (#2, now gone).

---

The idea of pulling the hinge pins was floated in comments. The hinge pins are on the other side of this door. If access is available, sure, just pop them out with a hammer and a thin tool. Most aren't locked in place unless it's an outswing door.

Answer (score 4):

The picture does not show the door frame, so I don't know what you are talking about re: "... without causing even more damage to the door frame." As it looks, just use needle-nose pliers to pull the parts out, and then go to your nearest hardware store and buy a new one. Install.

Comment: There's clear damage to the door stops, which are part of the frame, where someone apparently tried to Jimmy the bolt open.

Answer (score 4):

A screwdriver through the "hook" in the bolt should supply leverage enough to pry the bolt toward the center of the bore, removing it from the strike plate, allowing the door to open.

Comment: Where do you see a hook? What's visible isn't moveable. It's rigidly attached to the bolt sleeve, which can't be pulled through because of the faceplate at the door edge.

Comment: That u-shaped opening in what looks like a brass plate?

Comment: As I said, that doesn't move. If it did the burglary would've been successful and we wouldn't be having this odd discussion. :)

Comment: "As I said, that doesn't move."  It should move, provided enough force is applied.  The latch is clearly a total loss so there's no harm in trying to pry the bolt mechanism from the face plate on the door.  The face plate is made to hold the bolt against sideways forces so it might be weak enough on some greater inward force that some firm tugging could break it free.  I'd use something more sturdy (and less valuable) than a screwdriver though, a screwdriver could get bent.  Maybe a crowbar wedged between the "hook" and the inside of the hole and given a firm twist?  At least worth a try.

Comment: @MacGuffin That will most likely just break the thin layer of wood surrounding the bolt sleeve and make a huge mess of the entire area (but admittedly also unlock the door). Looks like there's just a couple of millimeters of wood left, certainly not enough to hold against the sideways leverage of a crowbar.

Comment: @TooTea  It appears you misunderstood the direction of twisting I refer to.  Put the flat of the crowbar vertically in the "hook" of the remnants of the latch so the other side of the blade is levered against the wood above the bolt inside the hole.  Twist the crowbar so it rotates on an axis perpendicular to the door.  This may only tear the "hook" from the rest of the latch remnants but I believe it is worth a try and would do little damage to the door.  Any damage done should be able to be covered by a new knob.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the security level of the door, you may be able to detach it from its hinges and then remove it from the frame. Or detach the hinges from the frame or break the hinges into two by extracting the pin. After the door is off the hinges, you can extract the wrecked bolt by unscrewing it.

Ordinary hinges are cheaper than doors, and sometimes very crappy. High security hinges are expensive and hard to break (doh!), so it may be cheaper to destroy the door so you can re-use the hinges if all else fails.

A locksmith / security company employee may know some tricks.

Comment: Looks like the door swings away from the side OP has access to, so probably can't see the hinges. Interesting point about the value of the hinges vs the door though!

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to (gently) remove the trim around the door, which could give some better access to the lock. For example, to allow access with pliers to the latch or ability to slide a credit card-like piece of plastic between the door to depress the latch. After removing the trim, you could also consider creating/cutting a gap at the edge of the door where it will be hidden by the trim. I replaced a couple of doors last year, removing and reusing the existing trim, so this should be possible on at least some doors. You probably want to have some matching paint available if you attempt this ...

Comment: Given that there appears to have been damage to the trim from an attempt to pry open the door removing the trim may not only be helpful in getting the door open but be done anyway to replace the damaged trim.  An excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If **really truly desperate**, use a keyhole saw to remove the wood around where the bolt goes.

Then repair with new wood and refit a latch bolt.

Actually, why not take the option of fitting a mortise bolt, whilst doing all this woodwork?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the remainder of that brass casing, you may be able to retract the bolt with a powerful magnet depending on the material of the bolt.